# bootstrap input-group-addon text disappears when form submitted and validated

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have a form that is contained in a bootstrap 3 modal and the from validation is done by Codeigniter when the form is submitted. Codeigniter returns the form validation errors for jQuery to run though and display.

I have a input combined with a input-group-addon to display the currency and the decimal value.

If submit the form with the input empty the then contents of the span tag after the input remains, but if I submit it with a value in the contents of the span tag is removed.

[image: Loaded from][image: Empty input submitted][image: Invalid value submitted][image: Valid input submitted]

My Html of the form

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-md-3">Project value</label>
       <div class="col-md-9">
             <div class="input-group">
                 <span class="input-group-addon">R</span>
                 <input name="proj_value" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text" >
                 <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
              </div>
              <span class="help-block"></span>
      </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code to displaying form validation errors

```
 $.each(data.messages,function(key, value){
                 var element = $('[name=' + key +']');
                 element.closest('div.form-group')
                 .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                 .find('.help-block').text(value);
 }
```

Comment: I don't think some. The $.each() is part of an if / else statement in the success part of ajax call.

Comment: @cfnerd it was a little piece of code earlier in the file that I forgot about that empties the contents of the element after the input... thanks for the help.